# jquery modal dialog doesn't work with modal:true

Tags: jquery

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Just trying to make it a modal dialog (dim out the page content).  I thought it is as simple as `modal:true`.  A dialog comes up when I click the image but it doesn't dim out the page content.

```
<img src="images/help-35-30.png" alt="Help" class="helpdetails" style="padding-left:30px;"/>
<div class="dialogplease"><p>A comment</p></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss/css/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.js"></script>       
<script>
$(function() {

$('.dialogplease').dialog(); //init dialog
$('.dialogplease').dialog('close'); //don't show dialog yet
$('.helpdetails').click(function(e) {
    $('.dialogplease').dialog('open')({
    modal: true
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you linking the jQueryUI css file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is wrong.

You should set this initially:

```
$(function() {    
    $('.dialogplease').dialog({modal:true,autoOpen:false}); //init dialog
    $('.helpdetails').click(function(e) {
        $('.dialogplease').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: Your first suggestion doesn't work.  But changing to set initially does.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why the first didn't work for you, it is proper syntax according to documentation. I'll just remove it from answer.