# Browse Button doesn't work in JQuery dialog when modal is true

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog, uploadify

I'm using uploadify fileupload control in my MVC3 application.

I'm trying to put the fileupload browse button in jQuery dialog box.

When i used the jQuery dialog box to render the content of fileupload, it worked fine in firefox but it doesnot work in Chrome.

I could see the `Browse` button in jQuery dialog box, but unable to click.

I've noticed that if `modal:true` is set to Dialog box, it is not working. If i comment out the modal it works fine.

However i could see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757265/jquery-modal-dialog-doesnt-work-with-modaltrue) post, but i couldnt help me. Still having the same issue

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="fileupload" style="display:none">
        <div style="clear: none;">
            File to Upload:
            <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" style="padding-left: 50px;"/><hr />
        </div>
        <p style="text-align: right;">
            <input type="submit" id="selectimage" value="Ok" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"/>
            <input type="submit" id="cancelimage" value="Cancel" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="cancelupload();" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btnImg" />
</body>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnImg").click(function () {
        $("#fileupload").dialog({
            width: '511',
            height: '200',
            modal:true,
            //show: "blind",
            position: [300, 500]
        });
    });
});
```

If i use

```
$('#fileupload').dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false });
```

prior to the above code, i'm unable to get the popup when btnImg is clicked

Any help could be appreciated

Comment: You are appending the dialog to HTML on open that is not necessary as dialog binds itself to the document, it also sets its own visiblity with no need for intervention.

Comment: But for my div i'm disabling the visibilty when page is loaded. You can see the html, i just have edited

Comment: Sure, you need to set it to display:none or visibility:hidden but you do not need to make it visible again. The dialog widget will make itself visible.

Comment: ok, Thank you @DavidBarker. I'll remove it. But problem persists

Comment: I didnt think it'd fix the problem, hence comment ;-). You might try adding `zIndex : 9999` to the property list for the dialog. That may give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: No, its not working though

Comment: I just noticed your dialog window is nested inside an `<input>` element. Take it out of this and place it in your `<body>` tag completely seperate to your input button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional from comments:

Uploadify has a z-index of 1 applied automatically that needs changing.

Add this to your CSS to fix the problem:

```
.swfupload { z-index: 100000 !important; }
```

Original answer:

Just tested this out in Chrome and the problem as far as my tests have gone is the HTML structure you're using.

jQuery-UI Dialog will take an element from anywhere in the DOM and display it as a dialog, it doesn't need to be nested within the input elements button.

```
<body>

    <div id="container">

        <input type="button" name="dialogOpen" value="open dialog!" />

    </div>

    <!-- using jquery uis helper classes to hide content is a better way than
         declaring inline styles -->

    <div id="modalWindow" class="ui-helper-hidden" title="Modal window">

        <h1>Example Modal Window</h1>
        <p>...</p>

    </div>

</body>
```

Notice that the modal window html is outside the container and hidden. This guarantees you that the stacking order of parent elements has no effect on the dialog html.

```
$('#container').on('click', 'input[name="dialogOpen"]', function(event) {

    // Using form buttons in some browsers will trigger a form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#modalWindow').dialog({
        width : 500,
        height : 200,
        ...
    });

});
```

As an extra, you don't even need DOM elements to create dialogs. You can build the dialog in jQuery or javascript and then call dialog on it.

```
// Create the new element, populate with HTML and create dialog
$('<div />', {
    'id' : 'modalWindow',
    'title' : 'New modal window'
})
.html('<h1>New modal</h1><p>Modal text</p>')
.dialog();
```

Comment: did you try with `modal:true` in browser

Comment: Yes, I use these modals all the time and they work in IE7+, Chrome and Firefox

Comment: If this is still an issue the modal is probably being displayed underneath other elements on the page. Try increasing the z-index or working out what elements have high z-indexs stopping the modal being above all other elements.

Comment: That also didnt fixed. I'll try giving more z-index

Comment: You dont still have this line in your code do you: "$('#fileupload').dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false });"?

Comment: Yes, i dont need it. I've seen in some questions to give that way as initializing the dialog.

Comment: ^^ yes remove it that will stop the above opening on click. If you do want to use it just call $('#modalWindow').dialog('open') in the 'click' event.

Comment: I think you have tried with normal buttons in `jQuery` popup. Normal buttons and fileupload control works with modal popup. But `uploadify` isn't working

Comment: Am sorry I dont have a link

Comment: Well just a a thought, give the uploadify buttons a higher z-index than the modal window.

Comment: Ok you're getting frustrated with someone trying to help you. If it's none of the above I'm afraid I can't help further. Apologies.

Comment: Hey sorry. I'm not frustated. You are trying to help me but its not working you can't do anything for my fault. Thank you for all your best effort

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915918/uploadify-inside-jquery-ui-dialog-chrome-opera-bugs take a look at that

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thank you for your time and patience. If you can add `.swfupload {
    z-index: 100000 !important;
}` css to your answer i'll accept as answer